# rewriting variable using for loop R

Tags: r

I've got a column in my dataset that contains a collection of 0,1 and 2.  The 2's are a weird leftover from some previous transformation, and I need to convert them to 1.  I've written a simple loop to do this

```
for (i in my.cl.accept$enroll){
  if (i==2){
    i=1
  }
}
```

however, this doesn't change the actual contents of the dataframe.  `ifelse()` doesn't work, because I don't need to change the other digits at all; just the number 2.

I've been using R a little more after coming from python, what simple thing am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: My.cl.accept$col[mca$col==2] = 1

Comment: `my.cl.accept$enroll[my.cl.accept$enroll == 2] <- 1` rather.

Comment: You need to change the values AND reassign them to a new variable. See many answers below.

Comment: @thelatemail thanks for the correction, could you explain why <- instead of =? Thanks

Comment: @imsoconfused - I prefer `<-` and am used to it, no big reason really.

Comment: @thelatemail oh so was there something else wrong with the answer i gave? I'm still learning R as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets generate a sample set:

```
set.seed(10)
DF <- data.frame(
  a=1:10,
  b=sample(0:2,10,rep=T))
DF
```

Now, replace every entry corresponding to 2 with 1:

```
DF$b[DF$b==2] <- 1
DF
```

Note: This is a vectorized method, and will always work faster than loop iterations.

Comment: That also changes `DF$a[4]` to `1` - you want: `DF$b[DF$b==2] <- 1`

Comment: just fixed it. Try again! 
You could also try: `DF[DF$b==2,2] <- 1` instead!!

Answer (score 0):

Dunno whether this is what you want?

```
> A<- 1:10
> B<- c(rep(0,5), rep(1,3), rep(2,2))
> data <- data.frame(A,B)
> data
    A B
1   1 0
2   2 0
3   3 0
4   4 0
5   5 0
6   6 1
7   7 1
8   8 1
9   9 2
10 10 2

> data[data$B==2,]$B <- 1
> data
    A B
1   1 0
2   2 0
3   3 0
4   4 0
5   5 0
6   6 1
7   7 1
8   8 1
9   9 1
10 10 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using `ifelse` correctly?  It actually **does** allow you to only change one value to another. Here's an example:

```
> x <- sample(c(0, 1, 2), 10, TRUE)
> x
## [1] 2 1 1 0 2 2 0 0 2 1
> ifelse(x == 2, 1, x)
## [1] 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1
```

For future reference, your good old-fashioned `for` loop should go something like this...

```
for (i in 1:length(my.cl.accept$enroll)){
  if (my.cl.accept$enroll[i] == 2){
    my.cl.accept$enroll[i] <- 1
  } else {
    my.cl.accept$enroll[i]
  }
}
```

Comment: True, but normal old indexing is probably more straight forward.

Comment: ha, never thought to write it like that...I guess I wasn't